# qplot with x-axis break into 2 regions for outliers

Tags: r, ggplot2

part of my data "plot.dat" is

```
   log2Exp   Days
  9.932601   0.0
  4.433500   0.2
  6.623776  1.0
  6.451625  2.0
  8.318600  3.0
  8.170948  5.0
  9.567554  7.0
  9.876911 14.0
 10.680653 28.0
```

most of the data are in first half of the x-axis (<=Days 14). if i simply plot the graph use

```
qplot(Days, log2Exp, data = plot.dat,cex.lab=1.5, 
      cex.axis=2, geom=c("point", "line"))
```

it is very hard to see the critical early change at Days 0.2 and 1 given  i will have multiple panels and lines. is there a way to plot graph normally from Days 0 to 14 and break the x-axis then plot Days 28 as if Days 28 is outlier.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use logarithmic scale using `scale_x_log10()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1 <-qplot(Days, log2Exp, data = plot.dat,cex.lab=1.5, 
      cex.axis=2, geom=c("point", "line")) + scale_x_log10()

library(gridExtra)

p2 <- qplot(Days, log2Exp, data = plot.dat,cex.lab=1.5, 
      cex.axis=2, geom=c("point", "line"))

grid.arrange(p1,p2)
```

[image]